# Swift - Wait for "dataTaskWithRequest" response before proceeding

Tags: php, json, xcode, swift

I know this question has been asked dozens of times before but unfortunately I'm not knowledgable enough with Swift to adapt those answers to my issue.

Basically I have a function that sends a POST request to a php script on a server but the response seems to take longer to receive than it does for my script to utilise the result. It sends a number variable and receives one as a response so I am also converting it from an 'any_object' to an 'NSNumber'.
From what I understand I need to implement a completion handler but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work with my code below.

```
var dataResult: Int = 0
var dataReceived: NSNumber?

    func remoteRand() {
        let dataToSend = 1
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/scripts/phpScript.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "dataToSend =\(dataToSend)"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                if (error != nil) {
                    self.displayAlertMessage((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    if let parseJSON = json {
                        let dataReceived = parseJSON["dataValue"]
                        self.dataResult = (dataReceived as! NSNumber).integerValue
                        print("\(self.dataResult) is server response")
                    }
                } catch { print(error)}
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        processResult()
    }

    func processResult() {
        print(dataResult)
    }
```

The result I get is:

```
0
1 is server response
```

How do I either make it wait for the response before proceeding to the next function or trigger the next function once completion is confirmed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task completes on a different thread than which it is called, this is by design so network requests don't stop execution on the main thread. So your block of code is sent off async and processResult is called before the network request is finished. You can put the call in the do block or add a closure to the method that can be called.

```
func remoteRand(completion: (response: Int) ->()) {

// your code
// process JSON
// get value
completion(dataReceived) 
// is passed back, just like the dataTaskWithRequest method to your caller where you can set the property on self, etc.
}
```

using it somewhere:

```
remoteRand { [weak self] (response) in 
    self?.dataResult = response
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Makes sense what you are saying and I think I have implemented your solution correctly but I get an error in the other functions that are calling the remoteRand() function as it requires an argument. "Missing Argument for parameter #1 in call error". It doesn't seem to accept anything I'm passing it.

Comment: Remove where you call it and type it out again, Xcode will auto complete the patter for the parameter where you can use it as shown above.

Comment: After reading your last comment I did what you said and then I had a moment of realisation where I thought it all made perfect sense and I had it figured out. I'm getting the response data accordingly but I still have same issue where the response is received after I need it. I want to post what I have tried but it's almost 3am and I need to get to bed. If there is any way you might be able to post your code in context to mine it would be greatly appreciated. When I get a chance next I will check it out and see how close I got. Cheers for all of your patience :)

Comment: Sure, it will take me some time but I will update my answer later for you.

Comment: Hi @thefredelement, I was just wondering if you managed to get a chance to have a look at that code for me. Cheers mate.

Comment: Ok so I can't believe I missed this before but I did what you suggested and added the call to the "do" block instead of trying to pass the result to a closure block and this seems to do the trick. I am yet to test it over the internet as opposed to localhost but I'm confident this should also work. Thanks again for all of your help. I will mark your answer as successful.